# Какая-то проблема с областью видимости в JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js

Сейчас делаю дерево из массива, есть рекурсивная функция, но при ее запуске выдает ошибку makeChildren is not defined

```
import {array} from './problems.js'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods: {
        makeTree() {
            console.log('тык');
            const arrayTree = array.filter((elem) => !elem.parentId); 
            console.log('тык2');
            arrayTree.forEach((elem) => makeChildren(elem,array)); 
            
            return arrayTree;
        },
        makeChildren(elem,arr){
            elem.children = arr.filter((child) => child.parentId === elem.id);
            elem.children.forEach((child) => makeChildren(child,arr));
        }
    }
}
```

Сам массив

```
export const array = [
    {name: 'Сфера медицины', id: 1, parentId: null},
    {name: 'Сфера it', id: 2, parentId: null},
    {name: 'Сфера искусства', id: 3, parentId: null},
    {name: 'Сфера стомата', id: 4, parentId: 1},
    {name: 'Сфера акушера', id: 5, parentId: 1},
    {name: 'Сфера хирурга', id: 6, parentId: 1},
    {name: 'Сфера пломбы', id: 7, parentId: 4},
    {name: 'Сфера наркоза', id: 8, parentId: 4},
    {name: 'Сфера брекетов', id: 9, parentId: 4},

]
```

Comment: `makeChildren` это не "простая" функция, это метод в объекте. Вызывать его нужно в контексте экземпляра - `this.makeChildren()`. Если в момент вызова `this` не доступен - его нужно сохранять при вызове метода `const self = this`. Тогда вызов метода будет выглядеть так - `self.makeChildren()`.

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, куда нужно воткнуть const self = this , чтобы self.makeChildren() прочитался? Я уже во всех местах перебрал :(

Comment: В самое начало `makeChildren(elem,arr){...}`. Вот так `makeChildren(elem,arr){const self = this; /* остальное */}`

Comment: Только сам вызов (первый) этого метода так же важен. Он должен быть в некоем контексте экземпляра объекта. Иначе `this` будет "утерян" (будет ссылаться не на экземпляр объекта) и метод будет "отсутствовать"

Comment: Постарайся сделать тестовый пример на котором можно будет что-то показать...